# Html canvas resize

Tags: reactjs, canvas, shapes, draw

I have html canvas with drawing functionality.
On resize window I resize the canvas and redraw all elements from react state.
But the drawn elements is not resized and are not on the same place relative to canvas margins.
The drawing is free style with  pen, so I need to resize that drawing. Its, not rectangles and circles, I know how to resize that.

Comment: Hello did you check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Where's your code, what have you tried? It's better to ask here with a more specific problem (after you've tried using search engines and a modicum of work)

Answer (score 0):

You can use scale method to resize canvas content on resizing window.

This is an example how to achieve it.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
let scale = 1;


const draw = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#aaa';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.scale(scale, scale); // <-- use scale before all drawings which should be scaled
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
  ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
  ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
  ctx.lineTo(700, 200);
  ctx.stroke();
};

const resize = () => {
    scale = canvas.offsetWidth / 500; // <-- change scale on resize
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * pixelRatio;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * pixelRatio;
    draw();
};

resize();

window.addEventListener("resize", (e)=>{
    resize();
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```